# using two tables in one field on a select in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

so I came across an issue  when creating a view because I need to get values from two tables but use the field (sorry if that's not worded correctly) for example -
table1 has legacy users
table2 has current users

and the statement goes like this

`select t1.firstname, t1.lastname from table1 t1;`

is there a way to get first and last names from table two to show in the same result columns as table one?
I know I could join the second table in and get the results as another column ex-

`select t1.firstname, t1.lastname, t2.firstname, t2.lastname from table1 t1, table2 t2`

sorry again if what I'm describing is convoluted

Comment: Look up `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `union all` to combine rows as long as you have same no of columns with same types aligned to the queries to be unioned. Also, you could replace `Union All` to `UNION` in case you don't want duplicates but in case you want both tables records so as to show records exists in both tables can keep union all

```
      select t1.firstname, t1.lastname from table1 t1
      Union all      
     select t2.firstname, t2.lastname
      from table2 t2
```

Comment: bingo that did it thanks! wasn't sure how to use unions